# How to use RethinkDB indices in the following scenario?

Tags: rethinkdb

I'd like to use an index to select `all documents that don't have a particular nested field set`.

In my situation with the JS-api this works out to this:

`r.table('sometable').filter(r.row('_state').hasFields("modifiedMakeRefs").not())`

How would I use an index on the above? I.e.: `filter` doesn't support defining indices afaik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write:

```
r.table('sometable').indexCreate('idx_name', function(row) {
  return row('_state').hasFields("modifiedMakeRefs");
})
```

And then:

```
r.table('sometable').getAll(false, {index: 'idx_name'})
```